# boostrap 4 alpha No funciona grids

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./Recursos/imagenes/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Recursos/css/style-login.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">col-xs-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ****************************************************************** -->
  <script src="./Librerias/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./Vista/Login/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No sé qué hago mal, en consola aparece todo bien y en vista no aplica los grids, los pone todos juntos los textos.

Comment: Para tu info.. bootstrap esta de momento en beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Bootstrap 4 desaparece la definición de clase *extra small* (`col-xs-*`) y se queda sólo como definición de columna por defecto (`col-*`). Lo puedes ver en la [documentación de Bootstrap 4 para el sistema de grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Ahora mismo tus columnas tienen la clase `col-xs-4` que no existe en Bootstrap 4, cambia la clase a `col-4` y ya funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./Recursos/imagenes/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Recursos/css/style-login.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-4">col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-4">col-xs-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ****************************************************************** -->
  <script src="./Librerias/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./Vista/Login/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```